# Got null object reference when send data using retrofit to server

Tags: android, mongodb

I'm trying to insert data into mongodb using Andorid device but when I send data Exception display:

> Process: com.example.transportor, PID: 1283
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'io.reactivex.Observable com.example.transportor.Retrofit.IMyServices.registercollect(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.transportor.ui.gallery.AddCollection_vente.addnewcollection(AddCollection_vente.java:201)
>           at com.example.transportor.ui.gallery.AddCollection_vente.access$000(AddCollection_vente.java:34)
>           at com.example.transportor.ui.gallery.AddCollection_vente$4.onClick(AddCollection_vente.java:158)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
>   01-17 15:50:30.880 1283-1283/com.example.transportor I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1283 SIG: 9

my code in IMyServices:

```
    public interface IMyServices {
    @POST("register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<String> registerUser(@Field("Email") String email,
                                    @Field("Fname") String Fname,
                                    @Field("password") String password,
                                    @Field("CIN") String CIN,
                                    @Field("AGE") String AGE,
                                    @Field("Role") String Role);
    @POST("login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<String> LoginUser(@Field("Email") String email,
                                    @Field("password") String password);
    @POST("facture")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<String> registerFacture(@Field("email") String email,
                                    @Field("date_insertion") String date_insertion,
                                    @Field("driver") String driver,
                                    @Field("client1") String client1,
                                    @Field("Product") String Product,
                                    @Field("TotalePrix") String TotalePrix,
                                    @Field("Region") String Region);
    @POST("collect")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<String> registercollect(@Field("creator") String creator,
                                       @Field("date_creation_col") String date_creation_col,
                                       @Field("emailcol") String emailcol,
                                       @Field("nom_col") String nom_col,
                                       @Field("long_col") String long_col,
                                       @Field("lat_col") String lat_col,
                                       @Field("tel_fix_col") String tel_fix_col,
                                       @Field("tel_mobile_col") String tel_mobile_col,
                                       @Field("adress_col") String adress_col,
                                       @Field("heure_matin_col") String heure_matin_col,
                                       @Field("heure_apresmatin_col") String heure_apresmatin_col,
                                       @Field("type") String type
                                       );
 }
```

and I use on MainActivity (in Oncreate):

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                    String Currentdate = df.format(c.getTime());
                                    addnewcollection("Alaeddine",Currentdate,Email,Client,long1,lat,Fix,Mobile,Adress,Seek
                                    ,Seek1,"collection");
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

private void addnewcollection(String creator, String date_creation_col, String emailcol, String nom_col, String long_col, String lat_col,String tel_fix_col,String tel_mobile_col, String adress_col, String heure_matin_col,String heure_apresmatin_col,String type) {

        compositeDisposable.add(myServices.registercollect(creator,date_creation_col,emailcol,nom_col,long_col,lat_col,tel_fix_col,tel_mobile_col,adress_col,heure_matin_col,heure_apresmatin_col,type)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String response) throws Exception{
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new SweetAlertDialog(AddCollection_vente.this)
                                .setTitleText("Creation de point de collection!")
                                .show();
                    }
                }));
    }
```

My problem that on debuging I found that all my `addnewcollection()` parameters are not empty.

Comment: `myServices` is `null` .. Show the full code, or at least how you instantiate that object.

Comment: But I inserted by the some steps user Infos and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on Service initialization:

```
//Init Services
Retrofit retrofitClient = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
myServices = retrofitClient.create(IMyServices.class);
```